# ¿como obtengo de un arreglo los datos que fueron creados cierto mes?

Tags: java, android-studio, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un json que tiene varios objetos y necesito que de un arreglo me regrese el total de dinero gastado en cierto mes.

El json es el siguiente:

```
{
 "results": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Venta",
    "created_at": "2019-05-10",
    "total": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "Venta",
    "created_at": "2019-04-10",
    "total": 200
  }
 ]
}
```

Por decir, si la venta fue realizada el 2019-05 que me regrese solo 100.
y este es mi codigo:

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
  for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
   totalMont += mJsonObject.getInt("total");
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría sería obtener la fecha del campo, convertirla a entero (quitando los "-" con .split) y lo compararía con la fecha que deseas, si entra en el if vas sumando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que has proporcionado he agregado un valor extra para la fecha 2019-05-15 así el array posee 3 elemento en lugar de 2 solo para realizar la prueba y esta es la solución mas simple que propongo:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestJsonArray {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String json  = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":1,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-05-10\",\"total\":100},{\"id\":2,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-05-15\",\"total\":100},{\"id\":3,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-04-10\",\"total\":200}]}";

    //Fecha para filtrar las ventas
    String fecha = "2019-05";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

   JSONArray ventas =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
   int total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < ventas.length(); i++){
        JSONObject venta = ventas.getJSONObject(i);
       //Validamos que la fecha created_at inicie igual que la fecha para sumar su valor
        if (venta.getString("created_at").startsWith(fecha)){
            total += venta.getInt("total");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(total);
  }
}
```

y esta es otra propuesta que es mas avanzada utilizando lambdas:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class TestJsonArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":1,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-05-10\",\"total\":100},{\"id\":2,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-05-15\",\"total\":100},{\"id\":3,\"category\":\"Venta\",\"created_at\":\"2019-04-10\",\"total\":200}]}";

        //Fecha para filtrar las ventas
        String fecha = "2019-05";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        //Convertimos el array  a stream
        Integer total = arrayToStream(jsonObject.getJSONArray("results"))
                //Hacemos cast del cada elemento del array a JSONObject
                .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                //Filtramos las ventas preguntando si el inicio de la fecha created_at es igual que la fecha a filtrar
                .filter(venta -> venta.getString("created_at").startsWith(fecha))
                //De los elementos filtrados obtenemos el total como int y se suma
                .mapToInt(venta -> venta.getInt("total")).sum();


        System.out.println(total);
    }

    private static Stream<Object> arrayToStream(JSONArray array) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(array.spliterator(), false);
    }

}
```